# How to know content type of an item stored in alfresco repository?

Tags: content-management-system, alfresco

I have a number of custom content types created in alfresco repository & I am uploading a number of items in alfresco of these types.

After uploading I want to determine content type such as cm:content or lj:doc or lj:invoice etc. of an item in alfresco. I tried with ContentService & DictionaryService but not helpful.

How can i do it?

Regards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use the nodeService:
nodeService.getType(NodeRef nodeRef) returns QName

Answer (score 0):

For more infos about the content type, you could use content.mimetype too !

Comment: content.mimetype is the mimetype of a d:content property. That's not the type of a node.

Comment: it's only if you want more information on a content type node